# Capacitive dropper failure

Tags: capacitive

I have some fridge led light based on basic capacitive dropper. If I connect circuit to AC mains nothing happens. At first I checked all components for mechanical damage and than measured them out of circuit. Mesaured X2 capacitor capacity looks OK, electrolytic capacitor also looks good, rectification diodes have correct forward voltage drop. Zener diode, leds tested. I expected at least one faulty component, but found nothing. I also tried to measure voltage acros zener diode, but I mesured really small value (as expected). I spent a lot of time to resolve this problematic circuit, but without any success. Which component can cause this behavior?
[image: Capacitive dropper led fridge light]

Edit: I tried to replace zener diode, which looks suspicious.
If I connect 9V to rectifier input, leds are emitting light.
I connected circuit to mains and leds are randomly flashing. I measured voltage acros C2, which was 20V and C3 14.7V. New zener was rated to 1.3W, which wasn't probably enought.

Edit 2: I replaced zener diode (rated to 2W), no change, but then measured voltage across all leds and there was about 13V. Leds still randomly flicker. Can be led diode damaged this way? If I connect DC 9V to rectifier input, leds lights, but when I connect circuit to AC leds randomly flicker?

Edit 3: Replaced leds solved issue, thanks for your help! :)

Comment: There's still enormously possiblities. Wrong connection or faulty joint? Or R3 much larger than 50 Ohms? Or some of the rectifier diodes conducts substantially to reverse direction. Put at first a resistor in parallel with C2 and see is there DC or AC or nothing.  SERIOUSLY: This kind of circuits are extremely dangerous. I recommend you to stop immediately. AC mains can be in your hands before you notice. In fridge water can be available without asking. You wouldn't ask whole question , if you were up to the task.

Comment: What is the voltage across c2 and c3

Comment: @user287001: I visually checked all connections and resoldered most of components. R3 is exactly 50Ohms. Rectifier diodes have the same correct voltage drop, I also measured voltage acros R3 and it seems to be DC.

Comment: @Snoggle: C2 is 20v and C3 is 14.7V. (currently measured values after zener diode replacement)

Comment: What are your leds? (=type, manufacturer) Do they have some control electronics which accepts only a nearly constant DC? A datasheet would be useful.

Comment: @user287001: Leds are directly mounted on small pcb without any additional resistors or control electronics. Led pcb is marked as  sw-bx02a-(a-a), I didn't find any useful information about used leds. Here you can see some [photos](https://www.espares.co.uk/product/es1756782/fridge-led-pcb).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Safety warning: assume the entire circuit is live when connected to the mains, even on the low voltage side.*

The circuit looks pretty standard to me.  It should produce about 9V across the diodes when on.

So either a component is faulty in a subtle way, or you've connected something up the wrong way round.  Remember that a zener diode is supposed to be connected reverse biased.  If the voltage across it is a fraction of a volt, it may be forward biased by mistake.

the current through the LEDs is quite high (perhaps 130mA).  Are they high power ones?

Edit:  I suspect the LEDs may be malfunctioning, perhaps because they have been fried by the high voltage and current.  A white or blue LED should normally have about 3 to 3.3V across it.  So three in series should be about 9 to 10V.  Without a data sheet, it's safest to assume LEDs can only handle about 20mA.  But ones specifically designed for LED lighting, and mounted on a heat sink (such as an aluminium curcuit board) may handle a lot more.

Other LEDs run at a lower voltage.  As low as 1.5V for red ones.

In normal use, the zener diode should do nothing.  It's there mainly to protect the rest of the circuit.  C1 provides the current limiting, and then the LEDs set the voltage.  If it gets to the point where the zener takes action, then the voltage is already too high.  This could be because an LED has failed, or because there is a voltage spike on the mains.

Comment: I try to be as careful as possible. Zener diode is connected in correct direction. Used diode for rectification is 1N4007, which is rated for 1A average forward current.

Comment: @dexterza I didn't word that well.  I meant the current through the LEDs.

Comment: Iam pretty sure LEDs are rated for this current. I tested them with DMM and all of them emitted light. I think one or more leds are partially damaged, when they are connected to lower current they work correctly, but they start to flicker as current rises to higher value. I replaced all leds with different ones and circuit is working, so probably my problem is solved (all I need is to order new leds with same package and replace them to confirm success).

Answer (score 6):

Start by debugging the low-voltage part of the circuit: apply ~9V DC to the input of the diode bridge (with both polarities) and see if the LEDs light up. If they don't, find the issue and fix it.

Once the low-voltage part is working, test with mains. Connecting the hot wire to B should make the whole circuit except A go hot as well, so if you lose mains voltage at some point, you know that's where the problem is.

Comment: This was a very good idea. It seems that low-voltage part is causing problem. Zener diode looks like the component, which probably  caused circuit failure.